# What is the Apple TV target Resolution?

Tags: screen-resolution, tvos

As mentioned above what is the target resolution for the Apple TV? For example like the iPhone 5 was 640x1136, and the iPad was 768x1024. I know that TVs vary in size so there is no *definitive* size. But maybe a  recommended size would work to have a starting point. Like having a fixed height and adjusting the width of the app to fit the tv.

Comment: I'm not totally sure but I believe it was 1920x1080

Comment: I tried the experiment of setting my new AppleTV to 720p, and the OS just scaled down my 1080p interface to fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apple TV standard resolutions for a modern 16:9 television are:

- 1920 x 1080 (1080p Full HD, preferred if supported)
- 1280 x 720 (720p for a HD Ready television)
- 858 x 480 (480p SD)

The new Apple TV runs apps at a standard 1920x1080 resolution at a 1x scale. This means that, when building tvOS apps, the screen size, in points, that you must use when building your interface is also 1920x1080.

Have a look here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-tvos-development--cms-24848